# How to delete multiple lines of the IPTABLES

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, iptables

Is there a way to delete multiple lines in an `iptables` not knowing what is in my `iptables`?

For example, I want to delete every port forwarding from port 80 and here is the `iptables`:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8080
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https redir ports 8443
```

Is there a way to delete these two lines in one command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working script:

```
 iptables -t nat --list-rules PREROUTING | while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  RULE443=$(echo $line | grep "REDIRECT --to-ports 8443")
  RULE80=$(echo $line | grep "REDIRECT --to-ports 8080")
  if [ "$RULE80" != '' ]
  then
    PORT80=$(echo $RULE80 | grep -o '\-\-dport.*' | cut -d' ' -f2)
    iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $PORT80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
  elif [ "$RULE443" != '' ]
  then
    PORT443=$(echo $RULE443 | grep -o '\-\-dport.*' | cut -d' ' -f2)
    iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $PORT443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
  fi
done
```